# Netbeans Java Interface won't display when called in the main class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have designed a Java Interface in Netbeans, however when I try to run it in the main class, instead of displaying, a blank new window is created in the corner of the screen.

This is my code:

```
private static User_Interface myUI = new User_Interface();
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException{

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            myUI.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I have already tried to implement advice from this question

[NetBeans Java Project Won't Display GUI Window Despite No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864752/netbeans-java-project-wont-display-gui-window-despite-no-error)

however this still doesn't help.

The interface code is all just the generated code from designing the interface, with a few setText() methods and empty actionPerformed methods. It does extend JFrame though.

Any help would be fantastic, thanks.

Comment: You create the `User_Interface` off of the EDT. This is a violation of the Swing threading model. Kudos for using `invokeLater`, but you haven't gone quite far enough.

Comment: `throws InterruptedException` smells like a `Thread.sleep` on the EDT == fail. Take out the `Thread.sleep(s)`, see what happens. Other than that, we need to see more code.

Comment: Sorry, the Thread.sleep() is in another method which I've commented out, although I forgot to take that out of the code I posted here. I've taken it out and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess.. There may be an issue with your **[layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)**. Set the layout to **null** or any other with which you are comfortable. In netbeans you have to select a layout according to your need. In my case the default layout was **gridBagLayout** that was alot pain for me while resolving the issue. Simply check your layout first. May be that resolves your issue.

Comment: Could you possibly walk me through how to do that?

Comment: Set layout in netbeans to null and redesign your GUI according to your need. This will take only 5-10 mins. Then run your GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time, it appears that the source code for the interface was missing it's initComponents() method.